# Can't post to facebook webpage with Admin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have some problems while trying to post something to a facebook webpage with an admin user.

This is my code, below I will post the whole problem:

```
FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 
status: true, 
cookie: true, 
xfbml: true, 
oauth: true });

function postToWall(address) {  
FB.login(function(response) {
    //console.log(response);
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed', 
            name: document.getElementById('linkTitle').value,
            link: document.getElementById('linkSubtitle').value,
            picture: document.getElementById('linkPhoto').value,
            caption: document.getElementById('linkCaption').value,
            to:address,
            from:address,
            description: document.getElementById('linkDescription').value
        },
        function(response) {
          if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post fué publicado.');
          } else {
            alert('Post no fué publicado.');
          }
        });
  } else {
    alert('El usuario canceló el login o no autorizó la publicación.');
  }
}, {scope: 'user_likes,offline_access,publish_stream'});
return false;
}

function logoutFacebookNJ(){
FB.logout(function(response){
    //console.log(response);
});
}
```

In address, I pass the facebook webpage id. I got it from this webpage: http://findmyfacebookid.com/

The promt with login appears and I use the user and password admin and then, I get a message of the las alert

I did some test and I can post to my user profile witouth problems. My app id is in developer mode.

Do you have any idea about what is my problem?

As one user asked, I print response from FB.login, this is what I get:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=0&skip_api_login=1&display=dialo…ale%3Den_US%26name%26picture%26to%XXXXXXXXX%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

What do I have to change to delete deny problem?

Now it permit me to login, and I get this:

```
Object {authResponse: null, status: "unknown"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    //        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true });
}

function postToWall(address) {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        //console.log(response);
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.ui({
                        method: 'feed',
                        name: document.getElementById('linkTitle').value,
                        link: document.getElementById('linkSubtitle').value,
                        picture: document.getElementById('linkPhoto').value,
                        caption: document.getElementById('linkCaption').value,
                        description: document.getElementById('linkDescription').value
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && response.post_id) {
                            alert('Post fué publicado.');
                        } else {
                            alert('Post no fué publicado.');
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            alert('El usuario canceló el login o no autorizó la publicación.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'user_likes,offline_access,publish_stream'});
    return false;
}

function logoutFacebookNJ() {
    FB.logout(function (response) {
        //console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Try this

Comment: I am still get the same error. This alert: alert('El usuario canceló el login o no autorizó la publicación.');

Comment: Deleting to and from, I can post to my profile login with my user and pass. But not to facebook page

Comment: Exactly the same result. I think the problem comes because I want to post as facebook page and not as user. Because as user it works. But as facebook page it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The code of posting is perfectly fine. Something's up with your login/authorization. Check out the `response` value of the **FB.Login** by `console.log(response);` and you'll get to know the exact problem.

You can also use the direct url:

> `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<APP-ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT-URI>&display=popup&caption=<CAPTION>&link=<LINK>&to=<PAGE-ID>&from=<PAGE-ID>`

and the login part will be handled by itself.

But one thing I can't understand why are you using the **feed dialog**  to post to the page, if the admin is only one who is posting to the page. You can instead use **FB.api** `/<Page-ID>/feed` to post directly without any dialog. But that's your call of-course.

Comment: Can you add info about FB.api for posting to webpage? I will check now what you said about FB.login in console

Comment: I added info about console.log(response)

Comment: About feed dialog, it is because I have to facebook pages with diferent administrator and I use the page address as parameter to post in one or the other. So I can login in whichever I want

Comment: Where do you want me to set console.log?

Comment: I have no problems about login as user and post in my wall. But, whenever I try as facebook page, it returns me this: Object {authResponse: null, status: "unknown"}

Comment: You are not getting the things correctly. I'm again and again asking you to check the response of 1) login 2) post. How can one help you without knowing the actual cause? You just need to check what the facebook response on these calls are.